# Display all elements in array from a response

Tags: c#, arrays, search, request

Ok I have a confusing question (I think) in regards to request and response values.

I created a request to search for Customers within a database based on the company name. Here is the code:

```
//Search through customers
        public void ArrangeRequest()
        {
            _request = new CustomerSearchRequest();                  
            _request.Company = "NewCustomers Inc";
        }
```

Here is customer info before it is requested and given values:

```
//Customer Info
        _request.Customer = new CustomerInfo
        {       
            Company = "NewCustomers Inc. ",
            CustStatus = Status,
            CustID = custid, 
            Fax = "(855) 555-6956",
            Phone = "(568) 895-6954",
            ProviderId = 56958,
            TechContact = _techcontact,
            TimeZoneInfoID = "Central Standard Time",
        };
```

This request works and when I debug I get the message that 52 customers were found. Now, each of those customers has a unique customer ID that was created when they were. When I debug I am able to see all the information for the customers including their customer ID. My problem is I am trying to output all those values to a text file. The problem is the customer ID's are in an array with all the other information in: `CustomerInfo[]`. Now I am able to output each individual value in the array by saying CustomerInfo[1] or CustomerInfo[2], but I want to be able to make the search and output all the values in the array without having to call each individual value.

I want this so that if I wanted to search for another company and it has 1000 results then I won't have to call each one obviously.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see a `CustomerInfo[]` in your code snippet. Could you post an example of what `CustomerInfo[]` looks like and what you want your output to be?

Comment: Are those IDs appearing in regular intervals, say every 40 fields?
If so, you could try and iterate through them with an integer i
`if i%40 == 0 { write Customer[i].ID to stream; }`

Comment: @lc., originally customer info is in a class of its own but when requested it stores all the values in an array (if that makes sense) but I posted an edit of what it is originally what it is before I request information from it.

Comment: I'm assuming there's more to the question than simply how to use `foreach` to enumerate an array, but still a little confused. Could you post an example of what you would do by using `CustomerInfo[1]`, `CustomerInfo[2]`, etc. that you are trying to avoid?

Comment: `log.WriteLine(_response.Customers[0].CustID);
            log.WriteLine(_response.Customers[2].CustID);
            log.WriteLine(_response.Customers[3].CustID);
            log.WriteLine(_response.Customers[4].CustID);
            log.Close();
        }`

Comment: YAre you askign about printing thse values in Immediate Window?

Comment: @sll, this will output to a logfile I made

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**edited based on OPs comments:**

```
foreach(var customer in _response.Customers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(customer.CustID);
}
```

Comment: This will just output the type of each 'item' e.g. `ConsoleApp.CustomerInfo`.

Comment: @DGibbs Not if `CustomerInfo`'s item has a proper `ToString()` override. :-P

Comment: Whilst that is true, I think the safest bet is to assume otherwise as OP has not provided full code...